# How to sum an array with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array with hashes:

```
[
    [
        {"created_at":"2013-11-16","position_f":1},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-17","position_f":3},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-18","position_f":0},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-19","position_f":1}
    ],
    [
        {"created_at":"2013-11-16","position_f":2},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-17","position_f":3},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-18","position_f":11},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-19","position_f":45}
    ]
]
```

Expected result:

```
 [
        {"created_at":"2013-11-16","position_f":3},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-17","position_f":6},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-18","position_f":11},
        {"created_at":"2013-11-19","position_f":46}
 ]
```

What is a easy way to sum those arrays with hashes and get a result under `Expected result`

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to sum only the values of `position_f` in the first hash of each array in the big array? or you want to sum all `position_f` values?

Comment: Yeah, this question was kind of hard to understand.  All three of us essentially answered a different question, depending on what you were looking for?

Comment: From the first array: `{"created_at":"2013-11-16","position_f":0}` + from the secound array: `{"created_at":"2013-11-16","position_f":0},` from the first array: `{"created_at":"2013-11-17","position_f":0},` + from the second array: ` {"created_at":"2013-11-17","position_f":0}` and so on... the `created_at` should be the same only the `position_f` should be `+`

Comment: @Alex could you please show us what you're expecting the result to be?

Comment: Thank you everybody, what I wanted was answered by `CDub`, `Arup Rakshit`, `hirolau`, and sorry for not explaining properly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is :

```
arr =[
        [
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>10},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>0},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>1}
        ],
        [
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>20},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>11},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>45}
        ]
    ]
p arr.inject(0){|sum,a| sum +=a[0]["position_f"]} # => 30
```

**update using [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)**

```
require 'awesome_print'

arr = [
    [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>1},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>3},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>0},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>1}
    ],
    [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>2},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>3},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>11},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>45}
    ]
]

nwar = arr.flatten.group_by{|h| h['created_at']}.map do |k,v|
  {"created_at" => k,"position_f" => v.reduce(0){|sum,h| sum += h['position_f']}}
end

ap nwar,:index => false
```

**output :**

```
[
    {
        "created_at" => "2013-11-16",
        "position_f" => 3
    },
    {
        "created_at" => "2013-11-17",
        "position_f" => 6
    },
    {
        "created_at" => "2013-11-18",
        "position_f" => 11
    },
    {
        "created_at" => "2013-11-19",
        "position_f" => 46
    }
]
```

Comment: the orthodox is: `sum + ...`

Comment: `1.9.3p448 :070 > arr.inject(0){|sum,a| sum +=a[0]["position_f"]}
 => 0 ` with the OP's data...

Comment: Did I miss something?

Comment: @CDub That's reasonable because the value of `position_f` in the first hash of each inner array is really equal to `0`, so `0+0=0` is correct.

Comment: So, this answer only handles one array with the first hash?  I expected a print out more like my answer...  Or am I really confused?

Comment: I guess what is `arr` in this answer?

Comment: @CDub the OP didn't give a clear idea about what he really wants to sum due to some language problems, I've asked him to do so because I'm totally confused whether he wants to sum all `position_f`s or only the `position_f` of the first hash of each inner array.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.  I think all three of us answered a different question.  The OP's question was pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Did not OP want the sum of the second elements as well?

Comment: @hirolau Yes..but OP updated it after I have given my answer.. But now I have given the answer...for last part also.. :)

Comment: `positions.flatten.group_by{|h| h['created_at']}` instead of adding the date on the beginning of the array, is adding an empty string, so I think because of that I get `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`, the array `{"":[{"created_at":"2013-11-17"`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to sum all the `position_f` values in all arrays, I would do:

```
sum = 0
outer_array.each do |inner_array|
  inner_array.each do |inner_hash|
    sum += inner_hash['position_f']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = data.flatten.group_by{|x|x[:created_at]}.map do |x|  
  val = x.first
  sum = x.last.map{|x| x[:position_f]}.inject(:+)
  {created_at: val, position_f: sum} 
end

p result #=>
    [{:created_at=>"2013-11-16", :position_f=>0},
     {:created_at=>"2013-11-17", :position_f=>0},
     {:created_at=>"2013-11-18", :position_f=>11},
     {:created_at=>"2013-11-19", :position_f=>46}]
```

Or if you do not care about the final presentation:

```
result = data.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |item,hash|
  hash[item[:created_at]] += item[:position_f]
end

p result #=> {"2013-11-16"=>0, "2013-11-17"=>0, "2013-11-18"=>11, "2013-11-19"=>46}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
data = [
  [
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>0},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>0},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>1}
  ],
  [
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>0},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>11},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>45}
  ]
]

@hash = Hash.new(0)

data.each do |arr_of_hashes|
  arr_of_hashes.each_with_object(@hash) {|arr_hash, master_hash| master_hash[arr_hash["created_at"]] += arr_hash["position_f"]}
end

@hash
```

Here's a run through IRB:

```
1.9.3p448 :020 > data = [
1.9.3p448 :021 >       [
1.9.3p448 :022 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>0},
1.9.3p448 :023 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
1.9.3p448 :024 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>0},
1.9.3p448 :025 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>1}
1.9.3p448 :026?>       ],
1.9.3p448 :027 >       [
1.9.3p448 :028 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-16","position_f"=>0},
1.9.3p448 :029 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","position_f"=>0},
1.9.3p448 :030 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","position_f"=>11},
1.9.3p448 :031 >           {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","position_f"=>45}
1.9.3p448 :032?>       ]
1.9.3p448 :033?>   ]
 => [[{"created_at"=>"2013-11-16", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19", "position_f"=>1}], [{"created_at"=>"2013-11-16", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18", "position_f"=>11}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19", "position_f"=>45}]] 
1.9.3p448 :034 > 
1.9.3p448 :035 >   @hash = Hash.new(0)
 => {} 
1.9.3p448 :036 > 
1.9.3p448 :037 >   data.each do |arr_of_hashes|
1.9.3p448 :038 >       arr_of_hashes.each_with_object(@hash) {|arr_hash, master_hash| master_hash[arr_hash["created_at"]] += arr_hash["position_f"]}
1.9.3p448 :039?>   end
 => [[{"created_at"=>"2013-11-16", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19", "position_f"=>1}], [{"created_at"=>"2013-11-16", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17", "position_f"=>0}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18", "position_f"=>11}, {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19", "position_f"=>45}]] 
1.9.3p448 :040 > 
1.9.3p448 :041 >   @hash
 => {"2013-11-16"=>0, "2013-11-17"=>0, "2013-11-18"=>11, "2013-11-19"=>46}
```

Then if you want the total, you could do:

```
1.9.3p448 :081 > @hash.values.sum
 => 57
```