# Sum arrays with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to perform an addition between those two arrays of hashes, for example I want to take from the first array, the first hash and sum `number, s_number, l_number` with the first hash from the second array, the sum will depend on the `created_at`, if `created_at` in the first array is equal with `created_at` in the second array perform a `+`. Please have a look at what I expect to be returned, as I don't know how to explain this better.

Thank you

```
raw_data = [
        [
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>6,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>4},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>1,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>1},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0}
        ],
        [
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>1,"s_number"=>41,"l_number"=>1},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>5,"s_number"=>45,"l_number"=>7},
            {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>7,"s_number"=>8,"l_number"=>2}    
        ]
        ]
```

What should be returned

```
[
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>7,"s_number"=>42,"l_number"=>5},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>6,"s_number"=>46"l_number"=>8},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>7,"s_number"=>8,"l_number"=>2}    
]
```

Update the hashes format is different then what I posted:

```
{:created_at=>Sun, 17 Nov 2013, :number=>0, :s_number=>0, :l_number=>0}
```

Comment: I was in the same situation yesterday, check this link: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076013/how-to-sum-an-array-with-hashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to sum the arrays:

```
raw_data.sum
```

This will return sth like:

```
    [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>6,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>4},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>1,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>1},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0}
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>1,"s_number"=>41,"l_number"=>1},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>5,"s_number"=>45,"l_number"=>7},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>7,"s_number"=>8,"l_number"=>2}    
    ]
```

Now, we need to group elements by 'created_at' key:

```
raw_data.sum.group_by{|element| element['created_at']}
```

This will result in:

```
{
    "2013-11-17" => [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
      ],
    "2013-11-18" => [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>6,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>4},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>1,"s_number"=>41,"l_number"=>1}
      ], ...           
}
```

We only need values of this hash:

```
raw_data.sum.group_by{|element| element['created_at']}.values

# =>
    [
      [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>0,"s_number"=>0,"l_number"=>0},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
      ],
      [
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>6,"s_number"=>1,"l_number"=>4},
        {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>1,"s_number"=>41,"l_number"=>1}
      ], ...           
}
```

And now we need to map each array of hashes to one hash. For this we'll use inject and merge function with a block:

```
raw_data.sum.group_by{|element| element[:created_at]}.values.map{|a| a.inject({}) {|result, hash| result.merge(hash) {|key, old_value, new_value| key == :created_at ? old_value : old_value + new_value}}}



# =>

[
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-17","number"=>2,"s_number"=>3,"l_number"=>4},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>7,"s_number"=>42,"l_number"=>5},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-19","number"=>6,"s_number"=>46"l_number"=>8},
    {"created_at"=>"2013-11-20","number"=>7,"s_number"=>8,"l_number"=>2}    
]
```

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Array into Hash`

Comment: I get this now... `expected numeric`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
result = raw_data.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |hash, result|
  date = hash.delete("created_at")
  result[date] = Hash.new(0) unless result[date]
  hash.each{|key, val| result[date][key] += val}
end.map{|date, hash| hash["created_at"] = date; hash}

p result #=> [{"number"=>2, "s_number"=>3, "l_number"=>4, "created_at"=>"2013-11-17"}, ...
```

Or perhaps even better as it will keep the order of the hash:

```
result = raw_data.flatten.group_by{|x|x["created_at"]}.values.map do |x| 
  x.inject do |result, hash| 
    result.merge(hash){|key, old, new| old.is_a?(String) ? old : old + new }
  end
end

p result #=> [{"created_at"=>"2013-11-17", "number"=>2, "s_number"=>3, "l_number"=>4},  {"created_at"=>"2013-11-18", "number"=>7, "s_number"=>42, "l_number"=>5} ...
```

Comment: For the first answer data you gave I get this error: `Date can't be coerced into Fixnum` and for the second one: `expected numeric`

Comment: So if the date is stored as a date and not a string, change the `old.is_a?(String)` in the last answer to old.is_a?(Date)

Comment: I did that, but is doing something strange: `[{"created_at":"2013-11-17","number":103,"s_number":102,"l_number":87}]`

Comment: Is that what you get from the raw_data above? That seems really strange? anyone have any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is here, I took the array format from another place apparently, this is how my date is sent.  `{:created_at=>Sun, 17 Nov 2013, :number=>0, :s_number=>0...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
output = []

raw_data.flatten.group_by {|x| x[:created_at].to_s}.each do |key, values|
  temp_hash = { :created_at => key.to_date }
  [:number, :s_number, :l_number].each do |attr|
    temp_hash[attr] = values.collect{|w| w[attr]}.sum
  end
  output << temp_hash
end

# output will contain your result
```

Comment: If you are runnung the above code in `irb` then you might get undefined method sum but it works in rails console. If you want to run it in pure ruby then just replace `sum` with `reduce(:+)` like `temp_hash[attr] = values.collect{|w| w[attr]}.reduce(:+)`

Comment: If you are getting undefined method `sum` or `+` then your hash must be having values as strings like `{"created_at"=>"2013-11-18","number"=>"7","s_number"=>"42","l_number"=>"5"}` . If this is the issue then you can simply use either `temp_hash[attr] = values.collect{|w| w[attr].to_i}.sum` or `temp_hash[attr] = values.collect{|w| w[attr].to_i}.reduce(:+)`

Comment: Now is returning null for each element in the hash. Please check my update. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_two_arrays_of_hashes(raw_data, keys = %w[number s_number l_number])
  raw_data[0].map.with_index do |item, index|
    if raw_data[1][index]["created_at"] = item["created_at"]
      sum_hash = {}
      sum_hash["created_at"] = item["created_at"]
      sum_hash.merge keys.inject({}){ |m, k| m[k] = raw_data[1][index][k] + item[k];  m}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
result = raw_data.flatten.group_by{|x|x["created_at"]}.values.map do |x| 
  x.inject do |result, hash| 
    result.merge(hash){|key, old, new| old.is_a?(String) ? old : old + new }
  end
end
```